# SharePoint Search Center issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with collaboration portal template on Windows Server 2008. The default search address for a site is pointed to /SearchCenter/Pages/Results.aspx. Any ideas how to change the address to some other address?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Search Center to use for your site by going to Site Actions -> All Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Search Settings.

The URL you need to change this to must be a site configured using the "Search Center" or "Search Center with Tabs" template.